# Logout functionality not working on back button

Tags: jsp, cookies, spring-security

Below is my jsp page , after logout when i click on back button it comes back to the previous page. please help me and tell me where i am wrong.

```
if (request.getSession(false) != null) {
    session.invalidate();
}
Cookie terminate = new Cookie(TokenBasedRememberMeServices.SPRING_SECURITY_REMEMBER_ME_COOKIE_KEY, null);
String contextPath = request.getContextPath();
terminate.setPath(contextPath != null && contextPath.length() > 0 ? contextPath : "/");
terminate.setMaxAge(0);
response.addCookie(terminate);



<c:redirect url="/welcome"/>
```

Comment: First off all why are you doing the logout yourself? Spring Security should handle this for you. Second when doing back you get the previous page in the browser cache, if you don't want this disable caching for protected pages by adding the appropriate headers.

Answer (score 0):

Got the solution just use the code to clear the cache in that jsp which has been included in every jsp.

code to clear cache

```
<%
     response.setHeader("Cache-Control","no-cache"); //Forces caches to obtain a new copy of the page from the origin server
     response.setHeader("Cache-Control","no-store"); //Directs caches not to store the page under any circumstance
     response.setDateHeader("Expires", 0); //Causes the proxy cache to see the page as "stale"
     response.setHeader("Pragma","no-cache"); //HTTP 1.0 backward compatibility
 %>
```